# Two bugs with a jquery toggle width animation

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, jquery

So I'm currently working on a website wich uses an animated logo I made with **JQUERY 1.10.2**

How it works: I have an Acronym "AD" and as soon as the mouse is over one of the letters, the full name slides out from the right of each letter.

It goes like so AD -> A...D... -> AcusticDream.

If you do not understand here is a LIVE DEMO on my site http://acusticdream.tk/TEST/

My code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".logo-firstletter").hover(function () {
            $(".logo-full").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Feel free to also look at my page's source code to see.

The **.logo-firstletter** class is self explanatory and the **.logo-full** is the other letters.

Bug #1
So the BUG is, the animation works pefectly, but if you put your mouse in the right(not over the first letter anymore) it will just animate endlessly... Try it by yourself to see..

Bug #2
If you just move your mouse repeatedly over the letters of the logo, it seems jquery will memorize how many times you put the mouse over so it will continue to animate and animate until the "count" is over.

Any help is appreciated and if theres a better way to do this I would welcome it too!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with this:

```
$(".logo-firstletter").hover(function () {
     if($(".logo-full").is(":animated")) return;   //Add this
     $(".logo-full").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500);
});
```

This way, we only animate if there is no current animation.

**Edit**:
Add a new wrapper element `logo-container` to your html, like this:

```
    <div id="logo-container">
        <div  class="logo-firstletter">A</div>
        <div class="logo-full">custic</div>
        <div  class="logo-firstletter">D</div>
        <div class="logo-full">ream</div>
    </div>
```

Then do:

```
$("#logo-container").hover(function () {
    $(".logo-full").animate({width: 'show'}, 500);
},function () {
    $(".logo-full").animate({width: 'hide'}, 500);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes it does help indeed :D but the only prob is, it makes it stay open, I still want it to close once the mouse has left it.

Comment: I see... I edited the answer, could you try it again?

Comment: Sadly, no it dosent and the main problem comes back(updated code on my site too so you could see)

Comment: Yes it solves everything! :D Thanks alot for your time and patience! Very smart too I understood what you did ^^ didint think about it.

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia